# P-adic norm/valuation of n!

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I am trying to figure out the valuation of n! with respect to some p-adic norm p.
This is part of a proof about the convergence behavior of $x^n /n!$ in the p-adics.

When I try and expand out n into it's value with respect to the p-adic basis i.e. $1, p, p^2 ,p^3....$ I get something pretty nasty to expand of course. Maybe this is the correct way to go about it and it just is something nasty.

Also, if anyone has resources on the p-adics avaialbe online they know, please let me know.

Comment: Since $n!$ is divisible by higher and higher powers of $p$, it converges to zero.

Comment: I understand the intuition, but I wan't to know a formal proof of it converging, and especially it converging faster than $x^n$

Comment: Are you asking about $x^n/n!\>$? And maybe about the sum of these, the exponential series?

Comment: yes I am, I'm sorry. I am trying to show that taylor's series converges. I will edit to make it clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $p$-adic order of $n!$ is 
$$ \sum_{j=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \dfrac{n}{p^j} \right\rfloor $$
(a theorem of Legendre).

Comment: I was preparing an analysis of the convergence properties of the exponential that used only the fact that the closest roots to zero of the logarithmic series $\log(1+x)$ have $v(\rho)=\frac1{p-1}$, but it got so long that I decided it was not a contribution to the discussion. Your answer is the best.